# Use of "Insofar" in term of progress

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "Progress Insofar" title in a presentation to show my work to date?

Comment: Insofar can't really be used like that, it'd be "Progress so far" or "Current progress". Insofar, insofar as I'm aware, requires a qualifying statement after it (like in what I just said). Correct me if I'm wrong, but insofar is essentially another way of saying "as far" and wouldn't be appropriate here.

Comment: It would be much better to use something like "Progress to Date" or "Current Status".

Answer (score 1):

No.

*Insofar* must always be followed by *as* and then a qualifying statement ([Source: Google](https://www.google.co.th/search?num=100&biw=1600&bih=758&q=insofar%20definition&oq=insofar%20definition&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l5.5806010.5814608.0.5814738.56.32.5.0.0.0.230.3373.0j22j3.25.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..30.25.2729.0.gKjKOLnCgQk)).

A great alternative in this situation would be '*thus far*.'